# Unable to use Spring Boot Data on Websphere traditional 8.5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websphere, websphere-8

I am trying to run a Spring Boot 1.5.9 application on Websphere 8.5.5.13 (class loading is parent last and I don't have shared library)
and when trying to call JpaRepository built in methods (I notice that the SQL query is being executed) but I am getting the following exception :

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: 
UOWManager transaction processing failed; nested exception is com.ibm.wsspi.uow.UOWException: 
java.lang.LinkageError: com/ibm/websphere/uow/UOWSynchronizationRegistry.registerInterposedSynchronization
(Ljavax/transaction/Synchronization;)V (loaded from file:/D:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar 
by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@873a9f67) 
called from class org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager$UOWActionAdapter 
(loaded from file:/D:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/D1SHLAPXXPWV1Node01Cell
/Spring.ear/SpringJSF.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar by 
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@7c146942[war:Spring/SpringJSF.war]
```

My pom file is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringJSF</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>  
    </parent> 

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>   
    </properties>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>   
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>               
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.15.Final</version>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId> 
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>SpringJSF</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.20</version>
               <configuration>
                  <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</argLine>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>



        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>


    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

My repository interface :

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Query("from Employee u where u.userName = :userName")
    Employee findByUserName(@Param("userName") String username);

}
```

Maven dependency tree:

```
[INFO] org.springframework:SpringJSF:war:1
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.5.9.RELEAS
E:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:comp
ile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.REL
EASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.9.R
ELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:com
pile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:c
ompile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile

[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compi
le
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:co
mpile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:1.5.9.RELEA
SE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.unbescape:unbescape:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:te
st
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.R
ELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1
:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:com
pile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile

[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.9.RELEAS
E:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:
compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE
:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.9.RELEASE:compile

[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.9.RELEASE:
compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.15.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar
:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.2.Final:
compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.2.15.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:
compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:1.5.9.RELEAS
E:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.2.3.RELEA
SE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.2.3.RELE
ASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:
compile
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:3.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:6.2.2.jre8:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish:javax.faces:jar:2.2.9:compile
[INFO] +- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.interceptor:javax.interceptor-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.ocpsoft.rewrite:rewrite-servlet:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.ocpsoft.rewrite:rewrite-config-prettyfaces:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile

[INFO] |  \- org.ocpsoft.rewrite:rewrite-integration-faces:jar:3.4.1.Final:compi
le
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
```

**NOTE:** any dao method annotated with **@Query works fine** with no issues, my current issue is with JpaRepository built in methods like findAll, it doesn't work and produces the above exception.

**UPDATE 1** : I tried marking the class loading to be parent first, and move all the jars from my application lib folder and put them in an isolated shared library, but this solution make the application started without springboot being initialized and neither hibernate nor jsf, so it's not working.

Comment: It seems a classloading issue. Check if under WEB-INF/lib of your web application the jar `jta.jar` is present. If present try to remove it and redeploy the web application and check if it is working. If it's working you must configure maven in order to not add the `jta.jar` under your classpath

Comment: jta.jar is not in the lib

Comment: May you post the maven dependency tree?

Comment: @Angelo Immediata, i updated the question and added the tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maven depdencency tree shows that you have 2 transaction API's as dependencies:

- `javax.transaction-api`
- `jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec`

and both have scope compile.

When you look at the lib folder of your war you should find

- javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
- jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar

You must ensure that both are not in the lib folder, because the `com.ibm.websphere.uow.UOWSynchronizationRegistry` is loaded from another class loader and this class loader also contains a version of the transaction api.

Try to use the `dependencyManagement` to set the dependency scopes to `provided`. E.g.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: I agree with this answer. Moreover be sure about the JTA version IBM Websphere follows. E.g. If it follows 1.1 you can't you 1.2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely caused by a copy of the JTA API packaged in the application loader.  That would cause the Spring transaction class and the WAS transaction class to link against separate copies of the JTA class, and the duplicate visibility from the Spring class (directly from the application loader, indirectly through the WAS class) causes the LinkageError at runtime.

This specific issue could likely be resolved by removing the JTA API from the application.  You may also want to reconsider the use of PARENT_LAST, unless you are certain it's required for your application - while it has its uses, it also greatly increases the likelihood of LinkageErrors and ClassCastExceptions, among other things, if the application's contents are not very tightly controlled.  A safer alternative might be a shared library with an isolated class loader, containing ONLY the specific libraries for which you need to bring your own implementation rather than simply using the version included in the server.